# Default value with WSGIApplication Handler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following code:

```
class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page_text, page=1): # page default value is 1, but it doesn't work

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/something/(page(\d+))?/?', MyHandler)], debug=True)
```

It should capture URLs like:

```
/something/
/something/page1
/something/page1/
/something/page2
/something/page2/
/something/pageN
/something/pageN/
```

When first URL is used (`/something/`), I still expect to have `page` equal to 1, but really `page` is equal to None. Why does it happen so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a workaround waiting for some regex guru answer:

```
class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, page_text = None, page = 1)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/something/', MyHandler)
                                     ('/something/(page(\d+))?/?',MyHandler)], 
                                     debug=True)
```

Comment: Now `page` is always equal to 1 (for ex. when url is `/something/page2`)

Comment: I think you should should replace ?/? with */*.

Comment: @daemonfire300, looks like SO deleted your code again. Try to mark that as `the code`, so it will be shown as is.

Comment: This is the right approach, rather than messing around with regexes with variable numbers of captured groups. Just modify the second regex to remove the outer parens and the question marks.

Comment: @Nick, could you please clarify why this is right approach? Why do I need to have two items at webapp.WSGIApplication for one handler? Will it fix the problem with default values?

Comment: @LA_ Because you're handling two different types of URL. The default value will be set if no parameter is passed, which is the case for the first handler.

Comment: @Nick, so if I have `/something/(\w+)?` and url `/something/` is used, then first parm will be always None, even if some default value is assigned? I.e. if I have handler `def get(self, parm1 = '')`, then (1) if url `/something/`, then `parm1` will be equal to `None`, (2) url = `/something/text`, `parm1` = `'text'`.

Comment: If your mapping line doesn't specify any groups, the default value will be used. If it does specify groups, the value from the group will be used - or None if that group is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nearly identical structure I use and I recommend it:

```
class PageHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self, page_id):

('/page/([0-9]+)', PageHandler),
```

I doesn't exactly answer the question but since I'm very pleased with that and it can do what you want (pages with ID numbers) you may find it useful.